# How can I host a backend service powered by web scraping using selenium web driver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, flask, web-scraping

So I am developing a project to scrape a website and deliver data to users, however I am using selenium/selenium web driver with python/flask. I was originally going to use beautifulsoup, but the website I am scraping requires some interactions on the page.

I have everything working with the scraper, I am just trying to figure out a way to make this work universally if I wanted to host this service on a website using a service such as heroku.

Currently Selenium is opening a chrome browser and scraping through the pages that way. Is there a smart way to do this without opening a browser and that will work seamlessly when hosted using some service?

Comment: You want Remote (or Grid if you need it to run in parallel)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "--headless" argument for your driver.

The argument will do the job but without opening an actual browser.

example:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"drivers/chromedriver.exe",options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this tutorial out: https://youtu.be/Ven-pqwk3ec. It shows how to set selenium up on Heroku. For your backend, you may want to run the script at a specific time using celery. Or if you want it to be triggered by user interaction you can also use celery for this async task