# How do i scrape a <li> from a eCom website using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below is my code

```
#scrape the main pro_list page of item
req = requests.get(croma_url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content,'lxml')

for title in soup.find_all('title'): 
    print(title.get_text())


pro_list = soup.find('div',class_='content-wrap')
for i in soup.find('div',class_='content-wrap'):
    for j in i.soup.find('ul'):
        for k in j.find('li'):
            print(k)
print(pro_list)
```

[image]

How do i Scrape the links of particular product?
Link of the eCom website: https://www.croma.com/

Help me extracting the

values of the products.

Comment: _using BeautifulSoup_, why tagging _Selenium_?

Comment: The entire site is behind `JS` so `BeautifulSoup` won't see a thing. You might want to check if there's an API or explore `selenium`.

Comment: okay i'll check for an API! cause later i wanna host this scraper, can i host a selenium based project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a javascript rendered page. You have to use selenium.

Using `selenium` + `bs4`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

url = 'http://croma.com/search/?text=Samsung+Galaxy+M31+Prime+Edition'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

soup=bs(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

for title in soup.find_all('title'): 
    print(title.get_text())


pro_list = soup.findAll('div',class_='content-wrap')
for j in pro_list:
    for i in j.findAll('ul',class_='product-list'):
#         print(i)
        for k in i.find('li',class_='product-item'):
            print(k)
```

Install the required package using `pip install webdriver-manager`

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly fine! But I want to host this scraper project, can i host a selenium based project?

Comment: Yes you can. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61571485/how-can-i-host-a-backend-service-powered-by-web-scraping-using-selenium-web-driv

Comment: If my answer helps then marks it as a solution by accepting it. shubho ratri :)